# laravel asset() doesnt find assets in public

Tags: javascript, laravel

I already put the folder named assets in my public folder and I should be able to access the assets like described on this page: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-asset

But for some reason It wont load and the browser console gives this error:

Loading failed for the   “http://localhost:8000/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js” when this should be the exact path

In the blade file I wrote this:

```
<script src="{{asset ('assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
```

I already tried with URL::asset and It doesnt find the file

I made the symbolic link 'links' => [ public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),

The real path of the file is /home/penta/ponti-gest/storage/app/public/assets/js

In my page I am using http

Comment: You should read [ask] and edit your question accordingly, people will mostly not waste time to check which extra information you added in different answers comments. Add to your question: The symlinks you put in place; The real path of the file you are trying to access; Specify exactly the error you are getting `It doesnt work` doesnt work here; Specify if you are using http or https in your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments:

> I already have the folder assets in my public/storage folder

> @GiuseppeP. Is the public/storage folder a symbolic link?

> yes I made the symbolic link 'links' => [ public_path('storage') =>
> storage_path('app/public'), ],

Your file is in the storage path.

This is accessible by using:

[storage_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-storage-path)

> The `storage_path` function returns the fully qualified path to your
> application's `storage` directory. You may also use the `storage_path`
> function to generate a fully qualified path to a given file within the
> `storage` directory:

```php
storage_path('app/public/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')
```

##### Addendum

Alternatively, you can use the `asset()` helper by prefixing the path with `storage/...`. I.e:

[The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

> The public disk included in your application's `filesystems`
> configuration file is intended for files that are going to be publicly
> accessible. By default, the `public` disk uses the local driver and
> stores its files in `storage/app/public`.
>
> Once a file has been stored and the symbolic link has been created,
> you can create a URL to the files using the `asset` helper:

```php
asset('storage/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')
```

Comment: I tried to do <script src="{{ storage_path('app/public/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script> and it gives following same error Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8000/home/penta/ponti-gest/storage/app/public/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js”.

Comment: using asset('storage/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

method `asset()` meaning go inside public folder
so if it doesn't work

```
<script src="{{asset ('assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
```

you should have in **public** folder **assets** folder then **js** folder
then the file **jquery-3.4.1.min.js**

hopefully that help you

Comment: I already have the folder assets in my public/storage folder

Comment: ok if you have ASSET_URL  in .env remove it and try again

Comment: @GiuseppeP. Is the `public/storage` folder a symbolic link?

Comment: yes I made the symbolic link 'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

Answer (score 0):

you must set [ASSET_URL](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/871ff9e65fea5588b1018d8770db6fc6ad37069d/config/app.php#L59) in your .env file.

then run

```sh
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: In my app.php config file I have 'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null), Where do I change it?

Comment: I tried to put ASSET_URL=public in my .env but it doesnt work and breaks adminLTE