# Stored images not showing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Here is my filesystem.php file :

https://pastebin.com/cUTur1d0

Method used in controller to upload file :

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  $file);
```

The view file :

```
<img src="{{asset("storage/".$post->image)}}" >
```

and did it :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Files are uploaded on localhost and the server too. Files are here.

But the images doesn't display, I don't know why.

On localhost it returns an apache 404 error (not laravel 404).

On production server it says laravel 404 error

Comment: try with `Storage::disk('public')->url($filename)`

Comment: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter::put(), 1 passed in /var/www/html/moviebrary/app/Http/Controllers/Back/BackPostController.php on line 81 and at least 2 expected

Comment: are you trying to access the file or upload the file to upload `->put($filename, $content)` to access file url `->url($filename)`

Comment: What's the absolute path of the image you're trying to access?

Comment: What's the result of `$post->image`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel asset() doesnt find assets in public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71218306/laravel-asset-doesnt-find-assets-in-public)

Answer (score 0):

1- In File explorer Check if public/storage link-file point to Storage/app/public

2- After php artisan storage:link

```html
php artisan optimize
```

now uploads will added to Storage/app/public not to Storage/app/

Comment: @Abduljameed, how to the 1- ?

Comment: Just click the shortcut storage folder in public folder

Comment: public/storage -> /var/www/html/moviebrary/storage/app/public. I don't understand, I do not have image files but folders :o ...

Comment: is the file in /var/www/html/moviebrary/storage/app